# compare a cell in a matrix with all the cells in another and store the result in a third matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to compare all the cells coordinates in matrix X, such that each cell is compared to all the coordinates in another matrix called Yint (Yint contains two columns and 65 rows each of which represents the coordinates (x,y) for a cell).

If the coordinates of a cell in X is equal to any of the coordinates in Yint then store 1 else 0 in a third matrix that is called labels.

Row 33 in Yint is just a flag in Yint matrix that's why I neglected it.

The problem is that the labels matrix always gives me zeros. I think there is something wrong in my code. Knowing that there are values in X that should satisfy the condition and store 1 at the labels matrix.

```
labels = zeros(65536, 1); 

Yint= round (Y);

counter=1;

for row = 1:1:rows
    for col = 1:1:cols
        pointer=1;
        for pointer=1:1:65
               if (isequal(row , Yint(pointer,1)) && isequal(col , Yint(pointer,2)) && pointer ~= 33)   
                   labels(counter) = 1;     
               else
                   labels(counter) = 0;
               end
         end
        counter=counter+1;
    end   
end
```

Matrices rows X columns:

Yint: 65 X 2

X: 256 X 256

labels: 65536 X 1

A reduced example:

```
X = [3  5  3;              
     2  7  4;                     
     1  7  2]                     

Yint = [1 1;
        2 3;
        3 3]
```

labels matrix can be viewed as:

```
labels = [1 0 0;              
          0 0 1;                     
          0 0 1]
```

However, we want it to be a vector (9x1) and what we get is:

```
labels = [1;
          0;
          0;
          0;
          0;
          1;
          0;
          0;
          1]
```

Comment: What are the comparison criteria? Please go into detail what the `if` conditions ***should*** express, because this is where the problem most certainly lies.

Comment: sorry, still not clear to me, can you give an example of input data and the desired output you want to get?

Comment: Okay, we want to find the left ventricle in a heart, so the input is a heart image (X) and we already know the coordinates of the left ventricle (Yint) the goal is to search for these coordinates in X and if found store 1 in matrix labels 65536x1 (all the coordinates of X in linear order) else 0.

Comment: Row number 33 is to differentiate between the endocardial and epicardial contours.

Comment: by 'example' I meant a numerical example of the input and output vector

Comment: In your example I don't see `X` to be square and `Yint` to be 2D, could you adjust that to give a reduced, but full example?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. Formatting issues. Now it's ready.

Comment: I am confused, you removed the `X()` reference in your if condition, how would that ever use the values contained in `X` then?

Comment: Don't use so many loops! Store index ranges in a helper matrix. Compare several elements at once, e.g. store `found = sum(A(1,:) == X)`, the test for `found > 0`. Don't use counters to linearize, use `reshape`. You might want to check out tutorials on MATLAB, because your code is not really how to approach problems in MATLAB.

Comment: @m.s. yes, I realized that I don't need the value inside the cells of X, I just need its coordinates. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @ypnos thank you, I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @m.s. y did you remove your answer? your's was clever. there is no fun in using built-in functions, i was about to up yours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given example and expected results, this should work:

```
Yind = sub2ind(size(X),Yint(:,1),Yint(:,2));
out = zeros(size(X));
out(Yind) = 1;
out = reshape(out.',1,[]).';
```

**Results:**

Input:

```
X = [3  5  3;              
     2  7  4;                     
     1  7  2];

Yint = [1 1;
        2 3;
        3 3];
```

Output:

```
out =

 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1
```

---

Additional work if you want to match all the occurrences instead of positions

```
Yind = sub2ind(size(X),Yint(:,1),Yint(:,2));

out = arrayfun(@(x) any(x == X(Yind)),X);
```

Your output(for the same input) will be something like this:

```
>> out

out =

 1     0     1
 1     0     1
 0     0     1
```

You could reshape this as you want:

```
out = reshape(out.',1,[]).';
```

After reshaping:

```
>> out

out =

 1
 0
 1
 1
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1
```

Comment: did not know about `sub2ind`, your solution is definitely more generic than mine

Comment: @m.s. Its a basic function.. BTW, i too learnt this very lately :( I guess your's need reshaping to match the output given by OP.

Comment: @m.s. when I replaced my code with yours I got two errors: Error using sub2ind: Out of range subscript. Error in LV (line 91) : Yind = sub2ind(size(X),Yint(:,1),Yint(:,2));

Comment: @user4326614 check your `X` matrix dimensions. it should agree with the coordinates (i.e `Yint`)

Comment: @SanthanSalai if you mean the matrices sizes, they're not. X is 256x25, Yint is 65x2 and labels is 65536x1.

Comment: @user4326614, i don't mean your matrix dimensions, i mean all the values of `Yint` should be lesser than or equal to 256.

Comment: @SanthanSalai They're, all of them are less than 200.

Comment: @user4326614 is my code working for your sample input? its working for me

Comment: @SanthanSalai Yes, your code is now working perfectly. The problem was the coordinates in row 33 in Yint they were (0,0) so they caused the error. Any idea how to jump it?

Comment: Thank you guys so much, you really helped a lot. And about the row 33 I replaced the (0,0) with an existing coordinate it Yint.